# Cannot display array data from App Delegate in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have built a meme generator and I have embedded the view controller that handles the meme creation inside of a tab bar view controller. The first tab displays a table view and I am attempting to have that table view display memes once they are saved via the activity view. I have added a memes array to my App Delegate file (I know this is controversial, but it is a requirement of this exercise) and I have confirmed that the meme is being saved and passed to the app delegate file.

I want to display the saved meme's image and text in the table view whenever the user creates a new meme. Here is what I have and this is not working.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewMemesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var memes: [Meme]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        memes = appDelegate.memes
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return memes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        let meme = memes[indexPath.row]
        cell?.imageView?.image = meme.memedImage
        cell?.textLabel?.text = meme.topText
        return cell!
    }

}
```

Where am I going wrong? The process of cellForRowAt is still new and frustrating for me. [Here](https://github.com/andrewTuzson/memeGenerator) is a link to the repo.

Comment: So you have 1 tab for meme creation, and another to view the created memes, right? And when you create a new meme on creation tab and go to view tab you don't find that new meme?

Comment: Close, yes. There are two tabs: the first for a table view and the second that will hold a collection view. The meme generator is being called by a nav bar button in each of the tab screens.

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you navigate between `UITabBar` tabs, `viewDidLoad` is not triggered, it is only triggered once the tab bar has been created.

In order to make the table view reflect the changes, you need to handle that in `viewWillAppear` not in `viewDidLoad`.

So you will have:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    memes = appDelegate.memes
}
```

And you'll need to add a property observer to `memes` like this:

```
var memes: [Meme]! {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Edit: As mentioned by @Andrea Mugnaini, you need to connect an `IBOutlet` for your table view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!
```

Comment: This is correct. Andrew also needs to attach `@IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView?`

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, that makes sense. I didn't realize that viewDidLoad is only called once. I thought it was every time the view was loaded. I am swinging at that now.

Comment: Do I need an IBOutlet if I set the datasource and delegate references in the storyboard?

Comment: Wait, that would be to reload the data, yes?

Comment: The reason that all this is needed is because an array is a value type so this `memes = appDelegate.memes` makes a copy of the array and so the two are not in sync.  One thing you could do is to wrap your meme list into a class and put that in the app delegate.  Then there will only be one instance shared between the view controllers.  Of course you still need to add in the viewWillAppear logic to reload the table but it prevents the array copying.  Another important thing is to add a call to super.viewDidLoad in your viewDidLoad.